# Plugin not working on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [blueimp's file uploader](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which requires the following to be called:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload();
```

I have some ajax loaded content that contains `#fileupload`, but the file uploader plugin doesn't work. How can I change the above snippet to work for ajax loaded content?

Thanks!

Comment: Call the filuploader again in the callback of the AJAX function. Perhaps in the done:

Answer (score 0):

After loading the ajax content simply call the file upload function again:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload();
```

Comment: I left out much of the extra lines of code (about 75 lines). It's more like `$('#fileupload').fileupload({dataType: 'json', add: function(e, data) { ...... }, progressall: function (e, data) { ...... }, done: function(e, data) { ...... } });`, etc. Is there no better way to load it without having to copy and paste the 75 lines of code to a different location?

Comment: Store the options in an object variable and just call the object for the options

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the newly created elements, to not have duplicated options put them in a var:

```
var fileupload_options = {
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    };
```

then just call each time a new element is created:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(fileupload_options);
```